excluding empty row in pivot table excel
I have created 2 calculated item in my pivot table excel (total créance and total retard ). However, empty rows are still displayed. If I delete the calculated item, the rows disappear.
I have tried hiding empty items in the field settings and applying filters with different values, but without success.
How to display a calculated item in an Excel pivot table while excluding empty rows or cells?


Add a new column e.g. "Display". In this column add a formula IF based on the value of the column "Reste à payer" with this logic: IF 'Reste à payer' <> "", "Nom du client", if not "".For example: =IF(B3<>"";A3;"") considering column B is 'Reste à payer' and column A is "Nom du client".
With this information use in Row Labels the new column "Display". You can rename it as you wish.
Create a situation where you'll have a blank row in "Display", update your Pivot, go to the Row Label field and unselect the Blanks. Then you every time you Refresh your Pivot, it there are blank fields in "Display", they'll not show.

Thank you so much, this tip helped me, but now there is only one empty line that appears.

I would find a solution by replacing =IF(B3<>"";A3;"") with =IF(B3<>"";A3;"Nan") and then applying an automatic filter to the new column with different from "Nan"."
